# The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception

Tags: linux, bash, .net-core, centos7

I'm getting a weird error while running my server under CentOS. It said it is `Unable to load DLL 'System.Net.Http.Native'` (see exception below), and it only occurs when I start the server during startup using systemd or manually in Linux Screen, not in regular shell (Bash, PuTTY).

Why is this happening? From what I have found on Google, it seems to be an issue with openssl-libs, but how come it is working in the shell?

Being quite new to Linux I don't know the difference between the environments.

### More details below

I use the same user in all cases.
The systemd .service is minimal, default type, only an After=network.target
The server does not use TLS/SSL encryption.

CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
Dotnet --version 2.0.3

Here is a list of the [dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x) (according to Yum). I've updated all packages so there are not later version available (in Yum).

```
libunwind.x86_64         2:1.2-2.el7 
lttng-ust.x86_64         2.4.1-4.el7)
libcurl.x86_64           7.29.0-42.el7_4.1 
openssl-libs.x86_64      1:1.0.2k-8.el7 
libuuid.x86_64           2.23.2-43.el7_4.2
krb5-libs.x86_64         1.15.1-8.el7   
libicu.x86_64            50.1.2-15.el7     
zlib.x86_64              1.2.7-17.el7
```

The exception details:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Http' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'HttpInitializer' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Net.Http.Native': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Interop.Http.GetSslVersionDescription()
   at Interop.HttpInitializer..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Http..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Http.GetSupportedFeatures()
   at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler..ctor()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler..ctor()
   at Veridict.LiveMap.ServerPlatform.Modules.GtfsRt.GtfsRtModule.Run()
   at System.Threading.Thread.ThreadMain_ThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

(I originally posted it on dotnet GitHub [issues](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25774))

Comment: Probably an environment issue. Compare the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` variables for both your shell context and the context of the systemd script. Use `exec 1<>/tmp/systemd.log` to collect output from systemd script.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That seems to be the issue. Will investigate more next week, and close the issue when I've confirmed it.

Comment: Confirmed. 
Adding `Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-dotnet20/root/usr/lib64"` to .service file did the trick.
Thanks